# How can I scrape table and find out corresponding entry for maximum number in particular column?

Tags: python, web-scraping

How can I scrape table from "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-9999&symbol=BANKNIFTY&symbol=BANKNIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17"

Then find out maximum "OI" under "PUTS" and finally have corresponding entries in that row for that particular maximum OI

Reached till printing rows:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import bs4 as bs

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-9999&symbol=BANKNIFTY&symbol=BANKNIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17'

html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
table = soup.find('div',id='octable')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
print row.text
```

Comment: Would you like to add python code if you are going to tag this as python question?

Comment: then do it if you want to :) and here is how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Drako thanks for the link, will keep in mind from next time and have edited the question.

Comment: @cricket_007added the code..can't move forward with finding maximum and henceforth

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate all the `<td>` inside the `<tr>`. You can do this with a bunch of for loop but using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is more straightforward. Using only this :

```
oi_column = [
    float(t[21].text.strip().replace('-','0').replace(',',''))
    for t in (t.find_all('td') for t in tables.find_all('tr'))
    if len(t) > 20
]
```

to iterate all `<td>` in all `<tr>` of your table, selecting only those rows with more than 20 items (to exclude the last row) and perform text replacement or anything you want to match your requirement, here converting the text to float

The whole code would be :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-9999&symbol=BANKNIFTY&symbol=BANKNIFTY&instrument=OPTIDX&date=-&segmentLink=17&segmentLink=17'

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

tables = soup.find("table", {"id":"octable"})

oi_column = [
    float(t[21].text.strip().replace('-','0').replace(',',''))
    for t in (t.find_all('td') for t in tables.find_all('tr'))
    if len(t) > 20
]
#column to check
print(oi_column)

print("max value : {}".format(max(oi_column)))
print("index of max value : {}".format(oi_column.index(max(oi_column)))) 

#the row at index
root = tables.find_all('tr')[2 + oi_column.index(max(oi_column))].find_all('td')
row_items = [
    (
        root[1].text.strip(),
        root[2].text.strip()
        #etc... select index you want to extract in the corresponding rows
    )
]
print(row_items)
```

You can find an additional example to scrap a table like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487876/scraping-and-parsing-multi-page-aspx-table/48489802#48489802)